# Reg ex that parses window.location.pathname and returns number of /s

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am looking for a regex pattern (and have been unable to come up with one) that can parse window.location.pathname and return the number of /s in it.

I am trying to keep all my path's relative to the home directory of my website.

For example: index.html has a script tag with an src="js/scripts.js". But that doesn't work if I access /episode/10/index.html. The path js/scripts.js is no longer valid. So my method is to write a simple javascript find and replace and return the number of /s in window.location.pathname. Subtract that number by 1 and change all the src to something like ../../

Any one know of a good quick easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just splitting on `'/'` and counting the number of array elements produced?

```
var slashCount = window.location.pathname.split('/').length - 1;
```

I can't shake the feeling that this is solving the wrong problem, though...

Comment: This is the most common approach, I don't see how it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about the split method. This is being done to get around using a CMS and to allow us to have a dev environment where all the pages function.

Comment: Glad you didn't pick my answer :(. Haha, but I know this is simpler. I didn't think of doing it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function I created:

```
String.prototype.count = function(a) {
    return this.match(new RegExp(a, "g")).length;
};
alert("Hi/how/are/you".count("/"))​;  // Alerts 3
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/rg9ZW/)

Just attach the `window.location.pathname` to this function:

```
window.location.pathname.count("/");
```

Comment: I think that by "/s" OP meant the number of `/`s instead of the `\s` spacing characters. +1 now `=]`

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate method is [*String.prototype.match*](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10):

```
var slashCount = s.match(/\//g).length;
```